# how to return the lowest number using filter JavaScript? Is there another solution?

Tags: javascript

```
let string = '10 200 100 1000 5000';

let arr = string.split(' ').filter(function (a) {

    return a.startsWith(1) && a.length === 2

})

document.write(arr)
```

Comment: View answer for additional questions about question.

Comment: there is something built-in for that, [`Math.min(...'10 200 100 1000 5000'.split(' '))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Answer (score 1):

We first split string to each individual piece with `(' ')` seperator and using map we go over each piece and convert each piece of string to a number with `parseFloat()`. Let's use `parseFloat` just in case there might be decimal values. Last step is to spread the array with `...` and to return the minimum value from array of numbers using `Math.min()`.

```js
    const string = '200 100 10 1000 567 5000 2314235423532';

    const lowest = Math.min(
      ...string.split(' ').map((piece) => {
        return parseFloat(piece);
      })
    );

    console.log(lowest);
```